# AWS Deep Learning AMI Virtual Environment Activation

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, deep-learning, virtual-environment

I'm trying to set up a Jupyter Server using AWS EC2 starting with a *Deep Learning AMI (Ubuntu) Version 7.0* AMI. It says that it comes with separate virtual environments:

> Comes with latest binaries of deep learning frameworks pre-installed in separate virtual environments: MXNet, TensorFlow, Caffe, Caffe2, PyTorch, Keras, Chainer, Theano and CNTK.

So I ssh into the instance and found an directory `~/anaconda3/envs/` which contains a bunch of folders like `tensorflow_p36`. But I was unable to find the **activate** files in them.

There doesn't seem to be any other folder that looks remotely like a virtual env so I'm stuck. Can someone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need a virtual env path? The different versions should be already available as kernels in a jupyter notebook. Is there anything else you need before starting a server?

Comment: @dennis-ec Yeah, I later noticed that as I started a server. The [outdated tutorial](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/deep-learning-jupyter-aws#comments) that I was following was using the ipython command to check the environment. That's why I was stuck. I'm still wondering if it's possible to use the virtual environments outside

Answer (score 1):

Try the command:

source activate pytorch_p36

Reference:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dlami/latest/devguide/tutorial-pytorch.html

When you login to the machine, the MOTD (Message of the Day) on the login screen displays various source activate commands you can run. To find the source activate commands of other Deep Learning frameworks, see this reference:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dlami/latest/devguide/tutorial-conda.html

Answer (score 1):

The `activate` binary is in `anaconda3/bin/activate`.
Your `PATH` is not set up correctly and therefore can not find `activate` binary. Specify it explicitly.

```
source anaconda3/bin/activate <env>
```